# String to date format python

Tags: datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert string date to date time format using datetime.strptime but i am getting ValueError

```
    lst[0] = 'Jan 02 2005'        

    from datetime import datetime
    datetime.strptime(lst[0].rstrip(),"%b%d%Y")
```

lst[0] is an element of a list. I am getting value for lst[0] from tkinter text wiget.
I am attempting different format since 2 hour but was not able to figure out what i am doing wrong here.
Could any one please help

Answer (score 0):

The format has to be exactly the same as the date string is provided.

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
lst[0] = 'Jan 02 2005'
date = datetime.strptime(lst[0].rstrip(), '%b %d %Y')
print(date) # prints 2005-01-02 00:00:00
```